# Is there a site that lists all EU members' Statutory Instruments for specific laws (like MLD4, UCITS etc.)

Tags: european-union, finance, ireland

I'm new here and don't have a law background but my field (finance) often overlaps with legal aspects quite a bit.

I was hoping someone might be able to steer me in the direction of a good (free!) online reference that I could search specific EU member statutes?

For the overarching directives etc. I have eur-lex.europa.eu which I've found good and I also have my local (Irish) statute (www.irishstatutebook.ie) but what would be really useful is a site where there was effectively a matrix of enacted law dictated by the EU per each member (like again, the UCITS regulations differ slightly form member state to member state).. does such a resource exist?

Comment: You say you're aware of eur-lex, but have you noticed the "national transposition" pages there (for example, https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/NIM/?uri=celex:32014L0091)?  If not, let me know, and I'll post that as an answer.  If so, please edit the question to describe why that doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: @phoog I wasn't aware of this function! pop it in as an answer and the 10 points are yours! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each directives page on eur-lex has a "national transposition" page.  For example, directive 2009/65/EC, concerning UCITS, is available at https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=celex:32009L0065.

There is a navigation box at the top left with several relevant pages:

- Text
- Document information
- Procedure
- National transposition
- Summary of legislation

(Before the recent site redesign, these were shown as tabs across the top of the page, so for the lack of a better term, I will call these "tabs.")

The *Document information* tab shows, among other metadata, relationships with other EU acts.  One useful section on this page is the *All consolidated versions* section, which is a set of links to consolidated versions of the document, indicated by date.

The answer to your question is the *National transposition* tab, which shows "National transposition measures communicated by the Member States."  It is worth noting the disclaimer:

> The member states bear sole responsibility for all information on this site provided by them on the transposition of EU law into national law. This does not, however, prejudice the results of the verification by the Commission of the completeness and correctness of the transposition of EU law into national law as formally notified to it by the member states. The collection National transposition measures is updated weekly.

The list of national acts is in the form of links, which lead to pages that seem designed to present the text of the national legislation, but in the examples I have checked say nothing more than "Text is not available."  Perhaps there are some instances, or will be in the future, where these contain links to national legal information sites.  As it is, there is enough information to enable one to search the national sites to find the relevant legislation.